# MkDocs deploy with python on gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, supervisord, mkdocs

Could every one help me please!

I have one problem with MkDocs deploy with my existing python project in nginx and gunicorn.

Problem is:

`If I use python run.py it's working fine, but I use supervisor gunicorn it's not work.`

Python script:

```
docs = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "site")

@app.route('/app/docs/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/app/docs/<path:path>', methods=['GET'], defaults={'path': None})
@app.route('/app/docs/<path:path>', methods=['GET'])
def static_proxy(path=''):
    if path[-3:] not in ['css', '.js', 'png']:
        path = os.path.join(path,'index.html')

    return send_from_directory(docs, path)
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Now fixed. Lolz.

Before I put this script in `run.py` it's not effected to @app.route('app/docs') then I moved it to other file`.py` it's working well!